# How can I fetch the Audio files from Android Device above Android 4.0 like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, audio, mp3

[image]

I want to show track same as Image and want to play it there.

Using below code I can try to fetch Mp3 files but can't play that file there.

So please help me..

```
     public void openGalleryAudio(){
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("audio/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
     }
```

Comment: have u know coustem Listview

Comment: Please Help .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method I can Find the detail of all Mp3 files from whole sdcard.
 In this Track_Bean is a Get and Set Method of Different String variables.

For Example

```
public class Track_Bean {
    private String mTitle = "";

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
 }
}
```

================================******==========================

```
 /**
* SD CARD QUERIES
*/
public ArrayList<Track_Bean> getAllSdCardTrack_Beans(Context context) {
ArrayList<Track_Bean> Track_Beans = new ArrayList<Track_Bean>();

    Cursor c = context
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID }, "1=1",
                    null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Track_Bean mTcBean = new Track_Bean();


             String mTitle = c
                     .getString(c
                             .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

             if(mTitle.trim().endsWith(".mp3") || mTitle.trim().endsWith(".MP3")){
                 mTcBean.setmTitle(mTitle);

                 String mArtist = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                 mTcBean.setmArtist(mArtist);

                 //Media Id
                 String mId = c.getString(c
                         .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                 mTcBean.setmId(mId);
                 //ALbumName
                 String mAlbumName = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                 mTcBean.setmAlbumName(mAlbumName);

                 String mAlbumID = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                 mTcBean.setmAlbumId(mAlbumID);
                 //Path
                 String mPath = c
                         .getString(c
                                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                 mTcBean.setmPath(mPath);
                 System.out.println("PATH"+mPath);
                //Duration
                 long mDuration = c
                         .getLong(c
                                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                 String mFormattedDuration = DateUtils
                         .formatElapsedTime(mDuration / 1000);
                 mTcBean.setmDuration(mFormattedDuration);

                 Track_Beans.add(mTcBean);
             }else{
                 System.out.println("The Track ext is not Mp3::"+mTitle);
             }

        } while (c.moveToNext());
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Size of array::"+Track_Beans.size());
    mLv_tracks.setAdapter(new Audio_Post_Adapter(Audio_Fetch.this, Track_Beans));
return Track_Beans;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this hope it was helpful for you

1. You have to pass the `intent`

---

```
private void getAudio() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,0011);
}
```

---

2. In `onActivityResult` you get `uri` of media

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  
    if (requestCode == 0011 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)){
            Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: 232"+audioFileUri);
    
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

---

[image]